# Unix C++ Third party API Call

Tags: libraries, c++

I am using an API exported from a third party SO file in my C++ application. That third party API is writing some messages to my unix console. I assume that API uses the concept of multithreading, as I can find the output coming into console is mixed (output from my program as well as out put from this third party API), as below:

- Message from my program: `My program`
- Message from API: `I am an API`
- Final output: `My I am an program API`

Is there there any method by which I can separate both the messages?
Third party SDK document doesn't provide any error/message handling mechanism or any thread synch mechanism.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is really a question for the originators of the library. Without a lot more information, it's doubtful that anyone here can give you the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thread output synchronization and buffering must be done on the level of the application that's outputting it. What you get is already interleaved and can't be reasonably put apart. All threads/processes are writing to the same file descriptor (and even worse, they each has its own output buffer, if they are using `stdout`), so if that application is not scheduling their output messages, the design is broken and there is very little you can do.

What kind of application is it? If it's a shell script wrapper, there's a chance the parallelisation is done on top and can be disassembled and buffered properly.